# Use of unresolved identifier 'boundingRect'

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions

I have very weird problem with below code.

```
extension String {
        func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
            let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
            let boundingBox = boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], context: nil)

            return ceil(boundingBox.height)
        }
}
```

It always throwing below compiler error.

[image]

But if I use `self.boundingRect` then it compile successfully and run the application but after launched app on simulator it automatically revert to again `boundingRect` (Removing **self**).

So everytime I need to add `self.` to execute app.

Comment: in here self identify your String

Comment: Even I'm doing this, but every-time it revert as I explained in question. Anyway I already got root cause of this problem through Prashant's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because the `boundingRect` is `NSString`'s `extension` method

```
extension NSString {

    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    open func draw(with rect: CGRect, options: NSStringDrawingOptions = [], attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]? = nil, context: NSStringDrawingContext?)

    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    open func boundingRect(with size: CGSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions = [], attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]? = nil, context: NSStringDrawingContext?) -> CGRect
}
```

So if you change  `String` to `NSString extension` it will  work

```
extension NSString {
    func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        
        let boundingBox = boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], context: nil)
        
        return ceil(boundingBox.height)
    }
}
```

**EDIT From Swift Team**

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8408

> The code in the compiler that says "NSString's members show up on String values" is specifically looking for member syntax, i.e. "foo.bar"—or in this case, "self.bar". It probably shouldn't have been written that way, but it was.
>
> I think we'd still recommend being explicit here, even if it's ugly: (self as NSString).boundingRect(…) or let nsSelf = self as NSString; nsSelf.boundingRect(…).

Comment: and questions inside answers isn't suitable too

Comment: Thanks Prashant. cheers! But Its really strange because it never throwing correct root cause of the problem. Anyway problem solved.

Comment: @Sh_Khan Do you know why this is happening /

Comment: @SunilTarge I will update answer as soon as I came to know why self is necessary and how it is bridge NSString --- String any way thanks for accepting answer

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Sure! Thanks

Comment: Yes I checked. Thanks for your efforts